# Excel does not show hidden sheet but if i unzip it, then there are 2 worksheets

Tags: excel, xlsx

So i was writing a program that reads excel files using a .net library and i got confussed when i saw that some excel file has 2 worksheets. I opened it up in excel and tried to use unhide option, but it was grayed out as if there was no hidden sheets but when i unziped the excel file, then there where indeed 2 files in `xl > worksheets` folder.

Why it cannot be unhiden? Is there other option that could make worksheet invisible? Or did excel create this worksheet for something and it cannot be unhidden?

Comment: Excel has the option of very hidden sheets... they can be unhidden from within the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out that apparently excel worksheet can have state of "Visible", "Hidden" or "VeryHidden". Excel options hide and unhide toggle between states of Visible and Hidden.

The question is, how and when excel changes worksheet state to `VeryHidden`?
It seems that it can only be changed to `VeryHidden` using Visual Basic Editor.
You can also unzip excel file and manually change it inside workbook.xml located in xl folder.

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be done using the Excel GUI. This can be done only through the Properties section of a sheet in the Visual Basic Editor, or by running a command such as `Worksheets("Sheet3").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden` in the Immediate window. If you're wondering how this could happen, perhaps a macro from another workbook did this by mistake!